# Highlight with different colours plot background with ggplot2 (based on y-axis values)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, boxplot

I have produced a boxplot with ggplot2(geom_boxplot), where I have continuous numerical variables on y-axis, and categorical variables on x-axis (scenario 1, 2, 4, etc...).

What I would like to produce is something resembling the graph showed in the attached picture, where geom_polygon was used to create the "coloured polygons" for the background, since numerical continuous variables were present on both x- and y- axes.

Is it possible to produce a similar graph with categorical x- axis, and numerical y- axis? In my graph I would like my "background colour bands" to be defined on the basis of y-axis values.

Thank you!

[image: example produced with with geom_polygon, continous numerical variables on both x- and y- axes]

I was looking into ggplot2 example graphs, but I could not find any relevant case.

Answer (score 0):

Sure is this possible with a discrete scale too. Using e.g. a `geom_rect` and a minimal reproducible example based on `mtcars`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) +
  geom_rect(
    data = data.frame(
      xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf,
      ymin = c(-Inf, 20),
      ymax = c(20, Inf),
      fill = c("red", "green")
    ),
    aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, fill = fill), alpha = .2,
    inherit.aes = FALSE
  ) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_identity()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Stefan, this is indeed very useful!
However, I am struggling to understand how can I edit the code for 3 or more colours. Is it too much to ask you if you have some indications for that, as well?

Comment: Each row of the dataframe I used inside geom_rect defines one band, i.e. the first row specifies the "red" band: `ymin` is the lower bound which for the "red" band I have set to -Inf, `ymax` is the upper bound, i.e. 20 for the "red" band and `fill` is the color. And finally xmin=-Inf and xmax = Inf mean that the bands should fill the whole range of the x-axis and must not be set.